# Can't find nan entries using numpy in array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can't find nan entries using numpy in array of strings my code is:

```
for x in X_cat:
    if x == np.nan:
        print('Found')
```

I know for a fact there are 2 nan entries inn the list but the code runs without printing anything. same if I replace np.nan with 'nan' My final objective is to replace the nan with the most common string.

Comment: Because `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`

Comment: @MedAli Because according to the question it's an _array of strings_.

Answer (score 5):

In an array of strings, you can only perform string comparisons.
You have to initialize a nan in a string format.

```
nan_str = str_np.array([np.nan]).astype(str)[0]
```

And by initializing an array like you describe it :

```
x = np.array(['hello', np.nan, 'world', np.nan], dtype=object)
```

You can then replace these `nan` by the most common string that I assume to be `mostcommonstring` :

```
x[np.where(x.astype(str)==str_nan)]='mostcommonstring'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because comparing *anything* with `NaN`, **including** `NaN`, is `False`. So even when `x` is `np.nan`, the `print` will not run. (In fact that used to be an acceptable way of checking if something was `NaN` as no other IEEE754 floating point value has that property.)

Use `np.isnan(x)` to check if `x` is `NaN`.

Comment: The problem is isnan won't work on strings if I try: np.isnan('l'), I get TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to comment on Thibaut's answer, but to simplify it:
The nan-string can be `np.str_(np.nan)` or even `str(np.nan)`.

`x = np.array(['hello', np.nan, 'world', np.nan], dtype=object)`

`x[np.where(x.astype(str)==str(np.nan))] = 'mostcommonstring'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check x for NaN with np.isnan:

```
for x in X_cat:
    if np.isnan(x):
        print('Found')
```

`np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`, so direct comparison is meaningless here. Find more about isnan in [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is sometimes used by programmers as convenient "filler" that can act like a number and silently propagate.  But mathematically, `NaN` represents expressions like `0/0` that can be essentially any number (if `a = 0 / 0`, `a * 0 = 0` and thus `a` can be anything)

Excepting an infinitesimally small probability, "any possible number" `==` "any possible number" is `False`.

Equality is a whacky concept once you get into `nan` and `inf` values (just try wrapping your head around [`1+2+3+4+5+... = -1/12`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)).  Just use the provided functions like `np.isnan`.

Answer (score -1):

You simply cannot find `np.nan` in an array of strings because `np.nan` is a number, not a string and all elements within a numpy array must have the same type.